# How to find a max value in a list of lists by the last row and column

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists and need to find the max value in the last list and last value of each list

```
score_matrix = [[6, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]

max_value, max_index = max((x, (i, j))
                              for i, row in enumerate(score_matrix)
                              for j, x in enumerate(row))
```

The code should find 5 as the max value however currently finds 6.

Comment: So it should find the maximum among 2, 3 and 5 (being the last values of each row)?

Comment: it should look at 2, 3 and 5 and also the max between [3, 4, 5] and find the max of those.

Comment: Then you need to make two separate tests; one for the last column, and one for the last row.

Comment: how do I access the last row that is my main problem.

Comment: For future reference: including another 1 or 2 examples that illustrate the rules would have helped. Like having the max somewhere else in that last row, or in the last column of other rows (with higher values elsewhere in the matrix that should not be returned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the *last* value in each row to count, only include that in the generator expression:

```
max_value, max_index = max((row[-1], (i, len(row) - 1))
                           for i, row in enumerate(score_matrix))
```

`row[-1]` takes the last value of a given row, and `len(row) - 1` produces the index of that last element.

If you also need the last *row*, then add those elements in a separate sequence; you can use [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to combine two generators:

```
from itertools import chain
max_value, max_index = max(chain(
    ((row[-1], (i, len(row) - 1)) for i, row in enumerate(score_matrix)),
    ((c, (len(score_matrix) - 1, j)) for j, c in enumerate(score_matrix[-1]))
))
```

This does include that column in the last row twice, but for one extra value it's not worth slicing the last row for.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> score_matrix = [[6, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]]
>>> max(chain(
...         ((row[-1], (i, len(row) - 1)) for i, row in enumerate(score_matrix)),
...         ((c, (len(score_matrix) - 1, j)) for j, c in enumerate(score_matrix[-1]))
...     ))
(5, (2, 2))
```

Comment: It also needs to compare last list as well so it is the max value of the last value of each row and also the last list in the list of lists

Comment: @AlexanderClarke: added that in.